# Grub2 upgrade error

Tags: grub2, upgrade

I got an error while upgrading Grub2, please need help.

```
mehman@hp:~/Downloads$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gimp gimp-data grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common libgegl-0.3-0
  libgimp2.0 libwhoopsie0 papirus-icon-theme whoopsie
11 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 24,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 472 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 grub-pc amd64 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2 [204 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 gimp amd64 2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34 [3.796 kB]
Get:3 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 grub-pc-bin amd64 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2 [897 kB]
Get:4 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 grub2-common amd64 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2 [529 kB]
Get:5 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 grub-common amd64 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2 [1.762 kB]
Get:6 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 whoopsie amd64 0.2.55.1 [22,8 kB]
Get:7 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libwhoopsie0 amd64 0.2.55.1 [9.982 B]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 gimp-data all 2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34 [9.482 kB]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libgegl-0.3-0 amd64 1:0.3.19~29-0z0~ppa~b6a36e7 [781 kB]
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libgimp2.0 amd64 2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34 [779 kB]
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 papirus-icon-theme all 20170729-1222+pkg6~ubuntu17.04.1 [6.007 kB]
Fetched 24,3 MB in 24min 49s (16,3 kB/s)                                       
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 330508 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-grub-pc_2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-pc (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2) over (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-grub-pc-bin_2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2) over (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-grub2-common_2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub2-common (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2) over (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-grub-common_2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-common (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2) over (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-whoopsie_0.2.55.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking whoopsie (0.2.55.1) over (0.2.55) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libwhoopsie0_0.2.55.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwhoopsie0:amd64 (0.2.55.1) over (0.2.55) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-gimp_2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gimp (2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34) over (2.9.5~139-4z4~ppa~4684702) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-gimp-data_2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34_all.deb ...
Unpacking gimp-data (2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34) over (2.9.5~139-4z4~ppa~4684702) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libgegl-0.3-0_1%3a0.3.19~29-0z0~ppa~b6a36e7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgegl-0.3-0:amd64 (1:0.3.19~29-0z0~ppa~b6a36e7) over (1:0.3.19~25-0z0~ppa~59af6bd) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libgimp2.0_2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgimp2.0 (2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34) over (2.9.5~139-4z4~ppa~4684702) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-papirus-icon-theme_20170729-1222+pkg6~ubuntu17.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking papirus-icon-theme (20170729-1222+pkg6~ubuntu17.04.1) over (20170727-1180+pkg6~ubuntu17.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.3.0.dfsg.1-1) ...
Setting up libgegl-0.3-0:amd64 (1:0.3.19~29-0z0~ppa~b6a36e7) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-9ubuntu2.2) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Job for grub-common.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status grub-common.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "start" failed.
● grub-common.service - LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/grub-common; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sat 2017-07-29 23:30:29 +04; 11ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 12747 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/grub-common start (code=killed, signal=TERM)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/grub-common.service
           └─12751 plymouth --ping

İyl 29 23:25:29 hp systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
İyl 29 23:30:29 hp systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Start operation timed …ing.
İyl 29 23:30:29 hp systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Record successful boot…RUB.
İyl 29 23:30:29 hp systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Unit entered failed state.
İyl 29 23:30:29 hp systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Failed with result 'ti…ut'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package grub-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (232-21ubuntu5) ...
Setting up papirus-icon-theme (20170729-1222+pkg6~ubuntu17.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Setting up libwhoopsie0:amd64 (0.2.55.1) ...
Setting up libgimp2.0 (2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc-bin:
 grub-pc-bin depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-pc-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc:
 grub-pc depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
 grub-pc depends on grub-pc-bin (= 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2); however:
  Package grub-pc-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2-common:
 grub2-common depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up gimp-data (2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Installing new version of config file /etc/gimp/2.0/gimprc ...
Setting up whoopsie (0.2.55.1) ...
Setting up gimp (2.9.5~141-0z0~ppa~bb93e34) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-9ubuntu2.2) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-common
 grub-pc-bin
 grub-pc
 grub2-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I do not want to restart my notebook, I know that it will not open again, please help me

Comment: Have you already tried to `apt upgrade` again?

Comment: I tried it, but it did not help me. I removed Grub2 and reinstalled and got the same problem

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Possibly: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1699482

Comment: This is strange. And the report is Confirmed, I hope they will fix it, because Ubuntu will not start without Grub. Thank you for reply

Comment: I extrapolated https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1655991 by commenting `. /lib/lsb/init-functions`; did a `sudo apt install -f` which only then worked. I then uncommented the line. Also changed /etc/default/grub to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="plymouth:debug" # quiet splash` & `sudo update-grub`. No idea what implications are but rebooted & it works. Had issues previously w/ NVIDIA so before `apt install -f`, I also did `dpkg -l|grep -i nvidia && sudo apt purge  nvidia-\*` and `sudo apt install sudo apt install nvidia-381 nvidia-settings` in my case but hope you won't need.